# Use several cloud storage accounts as a single big synchronized folder

Tags: windows, gratis, cloud-storage

Is there any free software that manage cloud storage such as google drive, drop box and sky drive with multi-account in the same time.

For google drive window local application, i can only register one account. How can I add the space of multiple accounts, and use them as a single folder?

Comment: What is your goal? A) Use only a single software? B) Use all of these small spaces as if they were a single big space?

Comment: B. One space to manage all account. It could be product or api.

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, you can't treat multiple accounts as a single folder, but for everything else [Expandrive](http://www.expandrive.com) is fantastic.  I use it for multiple cloud storage providers and it works very well on Mac and Windows.

Comment: Not mutliple accounts as a single folder. Maybe one account, one folder

Comment: After reading the introduction, it seems like a excellent software.

Comment: But It only offer 6 days for free trial.

Comment: Odd,  I received 30 days I think.  The author is very engaged with his customers. Send him a note and see if you can get a longer trial.   I just purchased on the Black Friday sale and my license covers both of my home machines in once.   Got the lifetime upgrades as well.

Comment: Any free alternative?